# JQuery can't get input value on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All I'm trying to do is get the `val()` of an Text Input. Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/tobadozole/edit?html,output).

I don't know if external links are allowed so I will also paste it here :

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="#test" class="form-control" aria-label="..." style='border-radius:4px;'>
</div>

<script>
  // Always shows up as undefined..not "".
  console.log($("#test").val());
</script>
```

Does anyone know why I cannot get the value of this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `#` sign from the `id` attribute :

```
<input type="text" id="#test" class="form-control" aria-label="..."  ..
//_____________________^
```

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Why can't I get the input value of the #test?</title>
</head>
<body style='padding:64px;'>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" value="test value" id="test" class="form-control" aria-label="..." style='border-radius:4px;'>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    // Always shows up as undefined..not "".
    console.log($("#test").val());
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah.. :( this is what happens when you stay up too long. Thanks though, for awhile there I thought it was something to do with the shadow element beneath the input.